# onchange event - IE error

Tags: c#, javascript

In my code behind, I have -

```
tbWhatIfBeginDate.Attributes.Add("onchange", "checkDates(" + tbWhatIfBeginDate.ClientID + ", " + tbWhatIfEndDate.ClientID + ")");
tbWhatIfEndDate.Attributes.Add("onchange", "checkDates(" + tbWhatIfBeginDate.ClientID + ", " + tbWhatIfEndDate.ClientID + ")");
```

and here is my javascript function -

```
function checkDates(BeginDateId, EndDateId) {
    if (BeginDateId.value > EndDateId.value) {
        var beginDt = new Date(BeginDateId.value);
        var endDt = new Date(EndDateId.value);

        var newDt = new Date(endDt.getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

        var y = newDt.getFullYear(),
        m = newDt.getMonth() + 1, // january is month 0 in javascript     
        d = newDt.getDate();

        BeginDateId.value = [pad(m), pad(d), y].join("/");
    }
}
```

when I run through Visual Studio 2010, it works.

When I deploy to my test server, I get an error message. "Object expected - Line:176,Char:1"

line 176 is - 
    input name="ctl00$cpMain$tbWhatIfBeginDate" type="text" value="8/1/2012"     id="ctl00_cpMain_tbWhatIfBeginDate" onchange="checkDates    (ctl00_cpMain_tbWhatIfBeginDate, ctl00_cpMain_tbWhatIfEndDate)" style="width:70px;"

I don't see an error.

Ideas?

Comment: Is it a JavaScript error? Then it maybe the line 176 of your JavaScript code not of the HTML code. Also sometimes you need to look at the next or previous lines then that what IE says.

Comment: @yunzen - it is a javascript error, but possibly how the actual file is loaded? I am still puzzled why this works through VS and not on my dev server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the id of HTML elements to the function, which are strings, but you pass it without quotes, as if it were a defined variable. In the `onClick` scope, there is no such variable `ctl00_cpMain_tbWhatIfBeginDate` already defined, so you're getting a javascript error. That's expected -- you've not declared such a variable.

In your function, you then immediately try to treat these arguments as objects, but again, you passed in `undefined` since the variables with the specified names didn't exist. Nor should they! When you're attempting to reference a DOM node by id, you have to use `getElementById` from the `document` object to "fetch" the related object. The ids, then, are just string.

As such, you should pass those strings wrapped in quotes. To do this, you need to modify the two lines where you add the events:

```
tbWhatIfBeginDate.Attributes.Add("onchange", "checkDates('" + tbWhatIfBeginDate.ClientID + "', '" + tbWhatIfEndDate.ClientID + "')");
tbWhatIfEndDate.Attributes.Add("onchange", "checkDates('" + tbWhatIfBeginDate.ClientID + "', '" + tbWhatIfEndDate.ClientID + "')");
```

That way, the string ids get passed to your function. Then, your function needs to be modified to get the DOM objects based on the passed ids:

```
function checkDates(BeginDateId, EndDateId) {
    beginDate = document.getElementById(BeginDateId);
    endDate = document.getElementById(EndDateId);
    if (!beginDate || !endDate)
        return; // <--- add an error message here?
    if (beginDate.value > endDate.value) {
        var beginDt = new Date(beginDate.value);
        var endDt = new Date(endDate.value);
        // existing logic here
    }
}
```

**Documentation**

- `document.getElementById` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById
- javascript functions - http://www.quirksmode.org/js/function.html
- javascript variables - http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptvariables.php

Comment: Adding the single quotes didn't fix the issue. I guess the broader question, why does it work in VS 2010 and not on my dev box, both without quotes?

Comment: yes. I am implementing new functionality that on page_load adds the required javascript references. Is it possible that my components need it added at design time?

Comment: Try to empty the `checkDates` function... just remove the function code and replace it with `function checkDates(BeginDateId, EndDateId) {
 alert("checkDates"); }`, tell me if you get the same error.

Comment: Do you know if there would be an issue with loading a js file and the calendar extender control and how/when the js file gets loaded?

Comment: That really depends on what the files did. If one **depends** on something that the other would do (declare object prototypes, etc), then the dependency needs to be loaded first.

Comment: Next, comment out both C# lines and use this code `tbWhatIfBeginDate.Attributes.Add("onchange", "alert('bob');");`, tell me what happens.

Comment: I get the alert when that event is fired.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12715/discussion-between-duckmike-and-chris)

Answer (score 0):

Are you going between a Cassini server and a 2003 box?  MS changed control naming going to IIS 7 / latest version of VS.  I would check what the actual variable names of your controls are in the rendered HTML.

Comment: I followed the naming convention I've used in the past. The difference here is all of my javascript exists in a different file.